# Confused about Android Roboto font - why can't I get a bold font?

Tags: android

I use the following styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyText">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>

<style name="StandardText" parent="MyText">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>

<style name="StandardTextBold" parent="MyText">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

This works fine on a Nexus 10. It even works on a Nexus S running 2.3.3 even though the `android:fontFamily` attribute is not availably on that SDK version.

On a Nexus 7 running 4.2.2 though, the `StandardTextBold` style won't make my Text Bold, even though the font is clearly Roboto.

Why can't I make my font bold on a Nexus 7?

Comment: Sorry but that is not at all helpful. The style is used in hundreds of TextViews in my app, I can't programmatically set them all.

Comment: see if its helpful for you or not

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889702/how-to-use-roboto-font-in-textview/18891745#18891745

Comment: facing the same issue. Hoe did you resolve it?