# How to use Roboto Font in TextView?

Tags: android, fonts, styles, textview

how to use roboto font type for my text views ?
I want to do it from xml and my app supports 4.1 above.
below is something which I tried:

```
 <style name="BubbleNumber">
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>    
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item> 
   <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/bubble_text_color</item>
 </style>
```

Answer (score 6):

Roboto is already the default font type (starting from Android 4.0)
see http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html

Otherwise you have to set the font programatically.

So I would recommend you to write a class:

```
public class StyledTextView extends TextView {

    public StyledTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        style(context);
    }

    public StyledTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        style(context);
    }

    public StyledTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        style(context);
    }

    private void style(Context context) {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                "fonts/roboto.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }

}
```

Then you can simply use it in your normal XML layout to replace the normal TextView

```
<LinearLayout
   android:width="match_parent"
   android:height="match_parent" >

    <com.your.packakge.StyledTextView
         android:width="match_parent"
         android:height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

For achieving roboto font type, You must add .ttf file of roboto in your asset folder. And set typeFace property to your text views. For example

```
TextView title=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(
    activity.getAssets(), 
    "roboto.ttf");
title .setTypeface(font);
```

You can't set it in xml.

Comment: This is not what the developer website says.

Answer (score 1):

I have done like this coz in my app all I need is all fonts are Roboto.
if you need to control edittext or in button then add a view class and 
extend it in custom text view or may be edittext then use it.

```
 public class RobotoTextView extends TextView {

        Context context;

        public RobotoTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            this.context = context;
        }

        public RobotoTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            this.context = context;
        }

        public RobotoTextView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.context = context;
        }

        public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
            if (style == Typeface.NORMAL) {
                super.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/RobotoNormal.ttf")/*
                                                                                                                 * ,
                                                                                                                 * -
                                                                                                                 * 1
                                                                                                                 */);
            } else if (style == Typeface.ITALIC) {
                super.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/RobotoItalic.ttf")/*
                                                                                                                     * ,
                                                                                                                     * -
                                                                                                                     * 1
                                                                                                                     */);
            } else if (style == Typeface.BOLD) {
                super.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/RobotoBold.ttf")/*
                                                                                                                     * ,
                                                                                                                     * -
                                                                                                                     * 1
                                                                                                                     */);
            }
        }

    }
```

now in your XML layout call it like this

```
                    <com.yourpakage.RobotoTextView
                        android:id="@+id/settings_cover_tv" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:text="Cover Photo"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a library [Android-RobotoTextView](https://github.com/johnkil/Android-RobotoTextView) that does that.

Comment: Thanks... that was useful!